# Ubuntu 20.04: DNS not working inside container

Tags: networking, dns, docker

Inside containers I get errors like this:

```
Can't connect to server (HTTPSConnectionPool(host='domain.com', port=443):
```

`root@2067c7f848be:/app$ cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

DNS is working correctly on the host:

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
```

Host settings:

`cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.0.1
search .
```

`cat /etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}
```

`cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8
FallbackDNS=9.9.9.9
```